# How PHP RedBean Handles DB Connection

Tags: php, redbean

I have heard about the ORM tool RedBean which is called as one of the best ORM for PHP. But I have confusion on handling DB connection in Redbean.

In documents they have mentioned to connect to DB (mysql), I need to use R::setup and close R::close.

Now, does it means If I create a web application, Do I need to call R::setup everytime before any CRUD statement and in last close the connection?

Does Redbean provides a feature like connection pooling?

Please suggest.

Comment: You need to call [R::setup with your connection info](http://www.redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/connection) (at least) once on application load (if you need the db connection). This is often done in a bootstrap file or "front controller" - in some attempts to implement MVC.

Comment: @JimL, okay so it means, if I call it once the connection will remain active in that user session until it close the application or I explicitly call close method?

Comment: It will be available for that request (one page load)  unless you close it